# Cakephp 3 - Query Fixture in IntegrationTestTrait

Tags: integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

I am having issues querying a loaded Fixture in my TestCase for an IntegrationTestTrait. I want to verify that a record already exist inside of a Fixture, then insert a duplicate record and verify that there is still only 1 record in the database.

During my test case initialization, I set the session variable for authentication.

```
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->loadFixtures(
            'Students', 'Users');

        // Configure Authentication
        $this->session([
            'Auth' => [
                'User' => [
                    'id' => 21896, 
                    'institution_id' => 1, 
                    'student_id' => null,
                    'contact_id' => 91, 
                    'email' => 'AuthenticatedEmail@school.edu', 
                    'role' => 'DSP', 
                    'is_admin' => false 
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        // Load Tables 
        $this->Students = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Students');

    }
```

In my Test Case, I check to see if the Database contains a record, then submit a POST request then test to see if the record did not insert.

```
    public function testAddStudentSuccess() {

        $data = [
            'institution_id' => 1, 
            'contact_id' => null, 
            'id_number' => '200XYZ', 
            'last_name' => 'Trimor', 
            'first_name' => 'Paul',
            'email' => '1_test@email.com'
        ];

        // Test Pre-condition 
        $query = $this->Students->find('all')->where([
            'id_number' => $data['id_number']
        ]); 
        $this->assertEquals(1, $query->count());

        $this->post('students/add', $data); 

        // Test Post-condition 
        $this->assertResponseSuccess();
        $query = $this->Students->find('all')->where([
            'id_number' => $data['id_number']
        ]); 
        $this->assertEquals(1, $query->count());
    }
```

However, when I run the Test Case, I get the following error:

```
Notice Error: Undefined variable: _SESSION in/var/www/html/samusg/src/Model/Table/StudentsTable.php, line 206]
```

A couple things:

- The last assertion works! After `$this->post('students/add', $data)` is submitted, the `$query` is populated with data.
- The first assertion does not work. I debug the Fixture before the `$this->post()` is called and it returns empty.
- In the Test Table, there is a test for `$_SESSION` variable, which is what line 206 referring to.

Long Story short: The Fixture is not populated with data during the start of the Test Case, but once the integration runs then the Fixture magically contains all the data. I get $_SESSION errors, but I already set the session in the `setUp()`, so I'm lost.

I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: There's some things missing here, your fixture code, and your model code. Also, make sure that you're actually targeting the correct database / using the correct connection. And because I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, tables have no business meddling with sessions, generally CakePHP apps shouldn't access any superglobals directly!

Comment: I am able to access the Fixture after the mock post request is sent. Therefore, I don't think it's a connection issue. I do agree with you that $_SESSION should not be accessed head on, I think this is the cause. I think the authComponent needs to be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to by pass this message by setting the $_SESSION super global directly on my Test:

```
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->loadFixtures(
            'Students', 'Users');

        // Configure Authentication
        $this->session([
            'Auth' => [
                'User' => [
                    'id' => 21896, 
                    'institution_id' => 1, 
                    'student_id' => null,
                    'contact_id' => 91, 
                    'email' => 'AuthenticatedEmail@school.edu', 
                    'role' => 'DSP', 
                    'is_admin' => false 
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $_SESSION = [
            'Auth' => [
                'User' => [
                    'id' => 21896, 
                    'institution_id' => 1, 
                    'student_id' => null,
                    'contact_id' => 91, 
                    'email' => 'AuthenticatedEmail@school.edu', 
                    'role' => 'DSP', 
                    'is_admin' => false 
                ]
            ]
        ];
```